# Find mismatches between two linked tables

Tags: php, yii

I have a bit of problem with my  `Yii 1.1` website.

I have two tables, `UserArtists` and `Artists`. `UserArtists` are being uploaded via file, and contains two fields `(hash, artist_id)` where `hash` is the user hash, and `artist_id` is the `id` of artist tables. `Artists` contains artists info.

The file, from which `UserArtists` is populated, is generated from outside source, and neither `hash` of `artist_id` is a match for our tables, so it contains both `hash` and `artist_id` values, that are not present in the actual data.

Now, what i need to do, is to add some statistics. I'm perfectly fine with `hash` mismatch, but i need to find out how many of `artist_id`'s that have been uploaded to our `UserArtists` table aren't present in out `Artists` table.

With pure `mysql` request i can achieve this result with:

```
SELECT COUNT(`ua`.*) FROM UserArtists `ua`
LEFT OUTER JOIN Artists `a` ON `ua`.`artist_id` = `a`.`id`
WHERE `a`.`id` IS NULL
```

But i have difficulties converting this query into a Yii `CDbCriteria`. Will be grateful for help.

**Edit:** Besides fetching this info for statistics (i could possibly do it with `CDbCommand`), i need to have an ability to delete all the records with invalid `artist_id`, and for this i need some way to do a custom query.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL-Query should be enough to delete the records in UserArtists where no match is found in Artists:

```
DELETE FROM UserArtists
WHERE artists_id NOT IN (SELECT artists_id FROM Artists)
```

This should return the number you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserArtists
```

You can do it this way:

```php
$sql = 'DELETE FROM UserArtists
        WHERE artists_id NOT IN (SELECT artists_id FROM Artists)';

$numberOfEffectedRows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->exectue();

$numberOfValidItems = UserArtists::model()->count();
```